# How to select the file whose name includes the newest date?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am importing a CSV file into a table in MS Access. 
However there are many files in the folder with the same extension and the names include dates in *"mm_dd_yyyy"* format.

Example: Lets say I have two CSV files:

- *my_music_02_10_2013_01_58_07_PM.csv*
- *my_music_02_11_2013_03_04_07_PM.csv*

Both files are in the same folder, *myfolder*. I want to import the file whose name contains the newest date.

Here is a short snippet of my code:

```
strPath = "F:\myfolder\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "my_music" & "*.csv")
```

How can I determine which of my *"my_music*.csv"* is newest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the key is to extract the Date/Time from each file name so that you may compare those to find which of them is newest.

Here is an Immediate window session testing the function included below.  The function returns null if it can't find a string which represents a valid date.

```vb
? DateFromFilename("my_music_02_10_2013_01_58_07_PM.csv")
2/10/2013 1:58:07 PM 
? DateFromFilename("my_music_no_date_here.csv")
Null

Public Function DateFromFilename(ByVal pFileName As String) As Variant
    Dim strBaseName As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strPieces() As String
    Dim varReturn As Variant

    varReturn = Null
    strBaseName = Split(pFileName, ".")(0)
    'Debug.Print "strBaseName: " & strBaseName
    strPieces = Split(strBaseName, "_")
    If UBound(strPieces) = 8 Then
        strDate = strPieces(4) & "-" & strPieces(2) & _
            "-" & strPieces(3) & " " & strPieces(5) & ":" & _
            strPieces(6) & ":" & strPieces(7) & " " & strPieces(8)
    End If
    'Debug.Print "strDate: " & strDate
    If IsDate(strDate) Then
        varReturn = CDate(strDate)
    End If
    DateFromFilename = varReturn
End Function
```

Comment: Hello HandsUp and thanks for the code: Here is the exact name of my files, the date changes in accordance to the time they are processed:
my_music_02_10_2013_01_58_07_PM.csv

Comment: So in this case it wouldn't matter if two files have the same time as long as they do not have the same name and same time?

Comment: Is the date part of the file name in *dd_mm_yyyy* or *mm_dd_yyyy* format?

Comment: Sorry for the late response: The Date format is; mm_dd_yyyy example: February 10 2013. Thanks again!

Comment: So when you are searching, are you looking for all files that have the word my_music, files with my_music and an acceptable date stamp, files with my_music that fall into a predeterminied date range, or files with my_music but only the one that has the lastest date?

Comment: Hello, I was hoping it was possible to only use the name of the file. Example: If file name contains the word my_music, rather than using the date. So if I have 10 files in the same folder, I will simply get the one with a specific name because files with different content cannot have the same name. Example: Music files cannot be movie files.